# TypeScript: Narrow type inference fails when destructuring array in function

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have the following object with a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const foo = {
  bar: ['a', 'b'],
} as const;
```

My goal is to write a function that updates the `bar` array and correctly infers the new type.

I can achieve the intended result when I pass `foo.bar` into the function:

```
type Bar = Readonly<string[]>;

function update<T extends Bar>(arr: T) {
  return {
    bar: [...arr, 'c'],
  } as const;
}

const updatedFoo = update(foo.bar);

// Inferred type is as expected:
//
// const updatedFoo: {
//  readonly bar: readonly ["a", "b", "c"];
// }
```

But I cannot get this to work when I pass in `foo` itself:

```
type Foo = Readonly<{ bar: Bar }>;

function update2<T extends Foo>(obj: T) {
  return {
    bar: [...obj.bar, 'c'],
  } as const;
}

const updatedFoo2 = update2(foo);

// Inferred type is too wide:
//
// const updatedFoo2: {
//   readonly bar: readonly [...string[], "c"];
// }
```

How can I rewrite `update2` to correctly infer the type of `bar` as `readonly ["a", "b", "c"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably to continue using `T` to represent the type of `bar`. We can give the parameter `obj` an object type having a property `bar` of type `T`.

```
function update2<T extends Bar>(obj: { bar: T }) {
  return {
    bar: [...obj.bar, 'c'],
  } as const;
}

const updatedFoo2 = update2(foo);

// const updatedFoo2: {
//     readonly bar: readonly ["a", "b", "c"];
// }
```

If you want to use the whole `obj` type as `T`, you will have to use a type assertion.

```
function update2<T extends Foo>(obj: T) {
  return {
    bar: [...obj.bar as T["bar"], 'c'],
  } as const;
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeBYAUDGAjAQwCcAuGAbQHIDKAaGSvSgXVuwF8YCIZRIoA3NmxQAngAcApjABCxFDABKkggBNwAG1EAeaEQCWYAOblmAPiFYRE6QDFEC5Ws060+YmTlEY7C8KxwAK5gwFD64DCB4qoEUJIATNoAKjCSAB5xYKo8XmYAFCB4AFZkboSkMCnsAJTo2LhEklCBRGB1OLjuFeQAdH2FRT3l9JTALGwdnNy84NCW7P580JHRsZKq9iDxClExcfF5CCDVltgA9Gcz-Ct765vxpeeXnTCNzmBaXWRv6h+iFAAiAgA+gAvAgmAA4AA5iWC4+IA)